# Could android:targetSdkVersion=8 be causing problems?

Tags: android

My Android application uses minSdkVersion=3 and targetSdkVersion=8.  I used 8 because that is the highest level of API the application was tested on; however, it was written for level 3 and does not use any features beyond that level (except one for level 4 using reflection).  Could using targetSdkVersion=8 be causing:

1. the Android Market to filter the application for some devices?  My intention is for the application to be available for ALL devices >= level 3 with NO filtering.
2. problems in the application since targetSdkVersion=8 will, according to google: "disable compatibility settings that are not required for the target version (which may otherwise be turned on in order to maintain forward-compatibility) or enable newer features that are not available to older applications".

Comment: To clarify, are you basically asking if users on say 1.5 or 1.6 can see your application on the market?

Comment: Yes, but more generally, (1) could it cause any filtering at all and (2) I did not test my app being installed on the SD card which EboMike says is a feature of 8. So should I lower it back to 4?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. `targetSdkVersion:8` just tells the system that you support SDK 8 features, like installing to SD card. `minSdkVersion` is what will filter the app and hide it for users with a lower SDK.

Comment: That's what I thought - I did not test installing my app on the SD card!  Should I lower targetSdkVersion=4?  Will that cause any upgrade problems for people who have installed the targetSdkVersion=8 version?

Comment: It won't cause any upgrade problems. I'd keep the targetSdkVersion at 8 if you want to support installing to SD card (which you should! Did you specify installLoation?). If you set the targetSdkVersion too low (3, I think), the system might think you don't support different screen resolutions properly.

Comment: I have an app with minSdkVersion=3 and targetSdkVersion=8 and it can be installed on SDCard on android 2.2 devices without any problem.

Comment: You don't need android:targetSdkVersion=8 to install on the SD card.  In fact, that has nothing to do with it.  Regardless of the target SDK version, you need to specify if it is okay to be installed on the SD card: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/install-location.html

Comment: Ha, I knew that Dianne would set me straight :) I think I based that off some (misguided?) comments in android-developers. However, IIRC a targetSdkVersion of 4 or higher is necessary for Android to not use compatibility mode regarding screen sizes and densities.

Comment: @hackbod: That link says the opposite. "In order to compile your application, change your build target to API Level 8. This is necessary because older Android libraries don't understand the android:installLocation attribute and will not compile your application when it's present."

Comment: When having to decide between the docs and hackbod, I think I'll choose hackbod :) But pydave, I think the docs are referring to the API target (i.e. in the build settings of the project), not the targetSdkVersion in the manifest.